# pcmC%iD%ip parameter in sprintf

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, printf

What does this line of code will do.

`pcm->card->number`, `pcm->device` both are `int`.

```
char str[16];

sprintf(str, "pcmC%iD%ip", pcm->card->number, pcm->device);
```

it is taken form android/kernel/sound/core/pcm.c.

Comment: The [documentation for `printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [the description of `sprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sprintf.html) and [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html), `%i` is

> The int argument is converted to a signed decimal in the style [-]dddd. The precision
>   specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be
>   represented in fewer digits, it will be expanded with leading zeros. The default precision 
>   is 1. The result of converting 0 with an explicit precision of 0 is no characters.

So the result is e.g. `pcmC12D23p` if `pcm->card->number == 12` and `pcm->device == 23`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess: this line is forming device's file name. Like ones which you can find in */dev*